# Waiting probability for multiple terminals, not a single terminal

Tags: probability, statistics, computer-science

There is an internet cafe with 20 terminals, 600 users, and an 8 hour open time per day. Assume that each user randomly uses the terminal once a day on average, and the usage time is exponentially distributed with 12 minutes on average.

Q. Calculate the waiting probability, the mean number of waiting users, and the mean waiting time for the terminal.

I would know how to solve this is there were only one terminal, but with the case of 20 terminals, I have no idea where to start. Could I have some help on this one?

Comment: As described, this is an M/M/20 queue with arrival rate $\lambda =1.25$ per min, and rate for each server $\mu=1/12$ per min for a combined service rate $20\mu = 1.67 > 1.25$ per min. So mean queue length and waiting times for service will be finite. (Technically, system capacity is 600, but that should not matter. Assuming rates are constant throughout the day there are about 75 arrivals per hour with capacity to handle 100, so some of the time there will be unused terminals and no wait.)

Comment: Maybe see [These class notes](http://courses.washington.edu/inde411/QueueingTheoryPart3.pdf).